# How to build Flac for BlackBerry Cascade?

Tags: blackberry-10, flac

I want to build Flac for a project I'm working on in Cascades on a Mac in Mometics.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/flac/files/flac-src/

I have in the past successfully built LAME and Ogg by just dragging the c and h files into my Workspace src folder before but that's not working with Flac. I have no idea about using make files, config, building libraries, etc.

Does anyone know how I can build Flac so that I can use it in my project?

I'm on a Mac 10.8.3, want to use Flac 1.2.1,
Mometics
Version: 10.1.0
Build id: v201303191709 10

Answer (score 1):

You need to cross-compile flac. Untar the sources somewhere, start a terminal and source the bbndk environment, should be something like:

```
. /opt/bbndk/bbndk-env.sh
```

depending on where you installed the sdk.

Then do the configure/make/make install dance,

```
./configure --prefix=/tmp/bbflac --host=arm-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0eabi --disable-ogg
make
make install
```

(I had to disable ogg support as I don't have that cross-compiled, if you need it you must build the ogg library first)

You can now pick the shared (libFLAC.so / libFLAC++.so) or static (libFLAC.a / libFLAC++.a) library and required headers from /tmp/bbflac and copy into your project.

Comment: Wow. Did it right before hitting the hay. Will test the lib later. Only the static library was made. I don't see a .so version anywhere. Anyhow, thanks. I'll mark it answered or not once I get to test it out later. And by headers do you mean the "include" folder's contents?

Comment: Static lib should be fine. And yes, the *.h header files you need from include to be able to use the lib from your sources.

Comment: Dang. I tried to add it to my project and I get " Library is not compiled for the correct architecture: /Users/dave/Desktop/bbflac/lib/libFLAC++.a" when I do Project-Add Library in Mometics.

Comment: Are you targeting the x86 based simulator or a real device? If simulator, you need to build it with the i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 toolchain.

Comment: I'm targeting a real device.